# Shiny Dashboard not connecting ggplots to drop down menu

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, drop-down-menu, interactive

I am trying to connect various ggplots to a shiny dashboard but am unable to. The dashboard works when I ran on its own but not in connection to the shiny dropdown menu. Below I have the code I am using:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

p_load(tidyverse, ggthemes, magrittr, lubridate, tidyquant, gridExtra,flexdashboard, knitr, RColorBrewer, hrbrthemes, anytime, plotly, shiny, dplyr,flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
 
Grammy <- read_csv("Grammy.csv") |> rename("Brandi Carlile" = "Brandi Carilie")


Grammy$Date <- strptime(Grammy$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

Grammy <- mutate(Grammy, Date = as.Date(Grammy$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
Grammy$Date <-anydate(Grammy$Date)
Grammy$Date <- as.Date(Grammy$Date)

Grammy$Date<- as.Date(Grammy$Date) #convert to date
Grammylonger <- Grammy |>
  pivot_longer(cols = `Brandi Carlile`:`Silk Sonic`, names_to = "Artists", values_to = "Streams")
```

The set up code for the data which I am using for my data the Grammys longer has 3 columns of date, Artists and streams while Grammys has Date and all the artists all the categories

````
{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("artists"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "Artists", label = "Artists", choices = c("Brandi Carlile", "Silk Sonic", "Brothers Osborne", "Carrie Underwood", "HER", "Justin Bieber", "Jon Baptise", "Lady Gaga", "John Legand", "Chris Stapleton", "NAS", "Billie Ellish", "Lil Nas X", "BTS", "J balvin", "Olivia Rodrigo"),
    selected = "Brandi Carlile")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(plotOutput("linePlot"))
  )
))


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
 test <- reactive({
    Grammylonger |>
      filter(`Artists` == input$Artists)
  })
  
  output$linePlot <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(data = Grammylonger(), aes(x = Date, y = Artists)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line(group = 1) +
      labs(title = "Artist Streams by day",
           x = NULL,
           y = NULL) +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels =  "%b %Y") +
      theme_bw() 
    print(p)
  })
})

```
````

When I run this code I see the drop-down menu however it has no plot connected to any of the names

Comment: As the `reactive` to filter your data is called `test` try with `ggplot(data = test(), ...)` to pass the filtered data to ggplot. Also, I would guess that you want to map the `Streams` column on `y`.

Comment: @stefan I added in those changes and am still having the issue of the drop-down displaying but unlinked to the ggplots

Comment: In that case I would suggest to make your issue [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing a snippet of your `Grammylonger` dataset using `dput`.